# Show that if $a, b$ are relatively prime integers, each of which divides $n$, then $ab$ divides $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Let $n$ be an integer. Show that if $a, b$ are relatively prime integers,
> each of which divides $n$, then $ab$ divides $n$

**Solution:**
If $a, b$ are relatively prime, then $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, so there are $s, t \in \Bbb Z$ such that $as + bt = 1.$ $\color{red}{(1)}$
If $a$ and $b$ divide $n$, then there are $u,v\in\Bbb Z$ such that $n = au$  and $n = bv$. Multiplying $\color{red}{(1)}$ by $n$
shows $n = nas + nbt = (bv)as + (au)bt = (vs)ab + (ut)ab = (vs + ut)ab.$
Hence, $ab$ divides $n$.

I don't understand why from $(vs + ut)ab$ deduce $ab$ divides $n$ ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It looks like $n$ is sometimes called $c$ here

Comment: My mistakes, I have edited it to c

Comment: Nervermind, i will use your edit

Comment: I have edited to n

Comment: Now do you understand how we deduce that $ab$ divides $n$?

Comment: Not really, I understand everything, except for this part

Comment: If $n  = (vs + ut)ab$ then $n$ is a multiple of $ab$.... that's all.  The *DEFINITION* of $k|n$ is that there is an integers $m$ so that $mk = n$.    So $vs+ut$ is an integer, and $(vs+ut)ab =n$ so .... there is an integer, $vs +ut$, so that $(vs+ut)ab =n$.  ANd so... $ab$ divides $n$.

Comment: Oh, I thought you didn't understand because it said $c=(vs+ut)ab.$  Do you understand with @fleablood's explanation?  $n=ab$ times some integer means $ab$ divides $n$

Comment: The first question to ask is "what is the definition of '$ab$ divides $n$'"?  So:  What does it mean to say $ab$ divides $n$?

Comment: Your explanation is very clear, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

It looks like $c$ was typed instead of $n$ in some places.  Try this instead:

If $a, b$ are relatively prime, then $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, so there are $s, t \in \Bbb Z$ such that $as + bt = 1.$ $\color{red}{(1)}$
If $a$ and $b$ divide $n$, then there are $s, t \in \Bbb Z$ such that $n = au$  and $n = bv$; multiplying $\color{red}{(1)}$ by $n$
shows that $n = nas + nbt = (bv)as + (au)bt = (vs)ab + (ut)ab = (vs + ut)ab.$
Hence, $ab$ divides $n$.

Comment: after I posted this answer, OP changed $c$ to $n$ in the question